# Cookie setting in hapi js but it is not storing in browser

Tags: node.js, cookies, hapi.js, refresh-token

I'm trying to setup the cookie in request headers in the following way.

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/login',
    options: {
      validate: {
        payload: Joi.object({
          username: Joi.string().required(),
          password: Joi.string().required()
        })
      }
    },
    handler: (request, h) => {
      // Generate a new access token
      const accessToken = generateAccessToken(username);
  
      // Generate a new refresh token
      const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(username);
  
  
      const response = h.response({accessToken,refreshToken});
      const refreshTokenOptions = {
        ttl: 60 * 60 * 24,
        encoding: 'none',
        isSecure: false,
        isHttpOnly: false,
        path: '/',
        // domain: '.abc.com',
        strictHeader: true,
      };
      response.state('refreshToken', refreshToken, refreshTokenOptions);
      return response
    }
  });
```

and I'm consuming this API and getting success response but the cookie is not stored in the browser.
The same API I tried in **postman** is successfully setting up the cookie in the postman cookie.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is a better approach to storing cookies(refreshToken).